# How to map Image saved in a document library to image column in another sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-list

Good day,

I'd like to ask how would you map automatically the image saved in sharepoint list to image column in another sharepoint list using power automate

So the scenario is a user would upload an image and would set the image name. What I want is create this same image or map it to another sharepoint list based on the name of the image. For example, I uploaded an image named GL Detail - Bal Sht Accts in a sharepoint list called Images. Now, I want it to be saved in a sharepoint list called Master Catalog, specifically in Preview Column where it should map the name of the image to the Report Name column.

This is the sharepoint list

[image]

This is the Master Catalog

[image]

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all?

Comment: I did try going for lookup columns but accordingly lookup doesn't support images columns